# Java parse "\n" as not line break

Tags: java, json, gson

I am parsing a json file using gson. Each line in the json file is one JSON object. In one of the fields, there is a bunch of unicode, coupled with \n

```
{"id":"12345", "text":"RT @abo_khalid_03: \u0644\u0623\u0646 \u0623\u0645\u0631\u0643\u0650 \u064a\u0647\u0645\u0646\u064a\ud83c\udf39\n\n\u0635\u0648\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0633\u064e\u0627\u0621 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0645\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u062c\u0645\u064a\u0639 \u0625\u062d\u062f\u064e\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0630\u0646\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u062c\u064e\u0627\u0631\u0651\u064a\u0647\u2757\ufe0f\n\n\u0641\u064e\u0625\u0646 \u0644\u0645 \u062a\u062c\u0639\u0644\u0651\u064a \u0644\u0643\u0650 \u062e\u064a\u0631\u064b\u0627 \u062c\u0627\u0631\u064a \u060c\n\n\u0644\u0627 \u062a\u062c\u0639\u0651\u0644\u064a \u2026"}
```

The entire thing is one line, there is only a new line char at the end of the JSON object. The "\n" characters in the field are treated as literally "\n". 
When I take this field out using gson and translate it into a string, gson turns the "\n" characters into line breaks and mess up the entire structure.

EDIT:
It appears that my JSON decoder (I am using gson) is interpreting "\n" as a line break (as it should, I suppose). My question is then, how can I parse the JSON field into a string without turning the \n into a line break?

Comment: `\n` *is* a line break. Java doesn't cause that.

Comment: that doesn't look very much like JSON to me.

Comment: Sorry, allow me to edit the text. I only pasted part of the JSON. This should make it more JSON-like

Comment: The only components of Java that translate the two characters \ and `n` to a line terminator are the compiler and the regular-expression compiler. Your problem lies elsewhere, most probably with the JSON decoder you're using, or else the data isn't properly formatted in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the \n is supposed to be two characters, a \ and an n, then it is not properly encoded JSON.  A JSON string would encode it as

```
\\n
```

Comment: The issue is that when I open the pasted text in any text editor, it is just \n, not a new line. If you go to: http://jsonlint.com and paste in the JSON I posted, you can see that it is valid JSON and the \n is treated as \\n

Comment: no, it is still a \n. That's how a new line is written in JSON. jsonlint.com is showing the JSON for the string, and the string contains newlines. If the string is supposed to have a SLASH and an n, it would have 2 slashes.

Comment: you can see that javascript interprets it as newlines, as it should: http://jsfiddle.net/4dugb1kb/

Comment: Interesting, is there a way I can parse the string without parsing the \n as a newline?

Comment: i don't know why you'd make \n a special case and not the \u. But, you can do a string replace after the fact, and replace \n with \\n. Or do a search/replace on your data files and replace all \n with \\n